# Angular ng -build ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: angular

> Here's my ng --version information installed in my system.

```
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.13.10
@angular-devkit/core                7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics          7.3.10
@angular/animations                 7.2.15
@angular/cli                        7.3.10
@angular/common                     7.2.15
@angular/compiler                   7.2.15
@angular/forms                      7.2.15
@angular/language-service           7.2.15
@angular/platform-browser           7.2.15
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   7.2.15
@angular/router                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                    7.3.10
@schematics/angular                 7.3.10
@schematics/update                  0.13.10
rxjs                                6.3.3
typescript                          3.2.4
webpack                             4.29.0


And my package.json file for the existing angular project:
```

ran npm install successfully, but when I attempt to ng build, I encounter the following error. Tried using open ssl legacy provider like how others have suggested but that didnt work.

```
ng build
 10% building 4/4 modules 0 active(node:8928) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 10% building 4/5 modules 1 active ...ar-cli-files\models\es2015-polyfills.jsnode:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);

                      ^
    
    Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
        at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
        at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
        at module.exports {
      opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
      library: 'digital envelope routines',
      reason: 'unsupported',
      code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
    }
```

** Node.js v18.19.0 **

Here's my package.json

Comment: Have you tried using a [supported version of node](https://angular.io/guide/versions#before-v9)?

Comment: Running this in terminal fixed the issue.

$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this in terminal fixed the issue.

`$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"`